# Show date and time together Jquery mobile Datebox

Tags: jquery-mobile, datetimepicker

I am using jquerymobile datebox to implement a calendar with time.

```
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/
```

I was able to set up the calendar successfully and select dates. But I also want to select the time. All the demos just shows how to set up a date picker and time picker separately. And what I want is both together. i.e in one click I should be able to select both the date and time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do so in the current version 1.1.0. You are welcome to vote on [this issue](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox/issues/295).